# Delete key in map

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a map:

```
var sessions =  map[string] chan int{}
```

How do I delete `sessions[key]`?  I tried:

```
sessions[key] = nil,false;
```

That didn't work.

**Update** (November 2011):

The special syntax for deleting map entries is removed in [Go version 1](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1ny8uI-_BHrDCZv_zNBSthNKAMX_fR_0dc6epA6lztRE&pli=1):

> Go 1 will remove the special map assignment and introduce a new built-in function, `delete`: `delete(m, x)` will delete the map entry retrieved by the expression `m[x]`. ...

Answer (score 350, accepted):

Go introduced a `delete(map, key)` function:

```
package main

func main () {
    var sessions = map[string] chan int{};
    delete(sessions, "moo");
}
```

Comment: Looking up the value and reusing it must be cheaper: `sessions["moo"] = sessions["moo"], false;` (or is that wrong?)

Comment: That crashes unless the key is present. I've added another solution based on your idea.

Comment: Is this safe to use while for-ranging the map itself?

Comment: @JorgeRamirez i don't believe so. if you want to do that find a way to iterate over a slice of the keys instead of the map object itself

Comment: Why is the second solution a better use of resources?  In the second solution you do two key lookups, whereas in the first solution, you one key lookup.

Comment: @thebiggestlebowski I don't think it is. It has been edited from the original where they remade the map in the first example, to use the new delete() syntax, but the original comments were never removed.

Answer (score 119):

### Copied from Go 1 [release notes](http://golang.org/doc/go1.html#delete)

In the old language, to delete the entry with key `k` from the map represented by `m`, one wrote the statement,

```
m[k] = value, false
```

This syntax was a peculiar special case, the only two-to-one assignment. It required passing a value (usually ignored) that is evaluated but discarded, plus a boolean that was nearly always the constant false. It did the job but was odd and a point of contention.

In Go 1, that syntax has gone; instead there is a new built-in function, `delete`. The call

```
delete(m, k)
```

will delete the map entry retrieved by the expression `m[k]`. There is no return value. Deleting a non-existent entry is a no-op.

*Updating:* Running `go fix` will convert expressions of the form `m[k] = value, false` into `delete(m, k)` when it is clear that the ignored value can be safely discarded from the program and `false` refers to the predefined boolean constant. The fix tool will flag other uses of the syntax for inspection by the programmer.

Comment: What do they mean by no-op?

Comment: @humble no operation occurs, no error, execution simply continues. I believe it comes from the x86 instruction `NOP` which simply makes execution proceed to the next instruction

Comment: @Alex Trivia item -- the NOP instruction dates back to at least the early 1950s, with the IBM 701's NoOp instruction.  I'm not sure myself if there's a precedent before that.

Comment: Why would deleting a non-existent entry be a no-op though? I would assume that it at least does a key lookup, as the compiler could in a general case not know if a key is part of the map.

Comment: @TheJP you are correct, but we don't mean a literal `NOP` instruction here. In this case "no-op" simply means that the state of the application will not change in any meaningful way due to the delete(). The delete()  has no lasting effect.

Answer (score 103):

From [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps):

> To delete a map entry, use the delete built-in function, whose arguments are the map and the key to be deleted. It's safe to do this even if the key is already absent from the map.
>
> ```
> delete(timeZone, "PDT")  // Now on Standard Time
> ```

Comment: `sessions.go:6: cannot use 0 (type int) as type chan int`

Comment: @Kinopiko: I don't think Jurily meant for the OP to use that code snippet. He just copied an example from the docs.

Comment: Looks like this has been removed since, getting `assignment count mismatch: 1 = 2 (use delete)`

Answer (score 47):

```
delete(sessions, "anykey")
```

These days, nothing will crash.

Comment: This is now the correct answer, I think. ["If m is nil or there is no such element, delete is a no-op."](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#delete)

Answer (score 1):

Use `make (chan int)` instead of `nil`. The first value has to be the same type that your map holds.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    var sessions = map[string] chan int{}
    sessions["somekey"] = make(chan int)

    fmt.Printf ("%d\n", len(sessions)) // 1

    // Remove somekey's value from sessions
    delete(sessions, "somekey")

    fmt.Printf ("%d\n", len(sessions)) // 0
}
```

**UPDATE:** Corrected my answer.

Comment: `sessions.go:6: cannot use 0 (type int) as type chan int`

Comment: Oops, forgot that I removed that too :P

Comment: `package main func main () {var sessions = map[string] chan int{};sessions["moo"] = make (chan int);}`

Comment: The above compiles and runs on my version of Go.