# How to acheive the order of insetion in nested maps using golang

Tags: go, data-structures, nested-map, go-map

In my project we are using nested map

```
map[string]map[string]map[string]string
```

for insertion of the data into cache.

While preparing the data the db data has to be compared with the cache data(nested map data).
Here is the concern: we need order of insertion to be preserved in this nested map.

Answer (score 0):

This is in relation with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74092090/6309), and you need to check why the order would need to be preserved.

[Comparing map in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18208394/6309) does not depend on the order, and [Go runtime does not maintain the iteration orders for maps](https://go101.org/article/unofficial-faq.html#map-iteration-order).